# Manhattan distance for K-medoids in matlab

Tags: matlab, edit-distance

I am trying to use  Matlab k-medoids function.

I found these points:

1- k-medoids 'build' function is different than the original 'pam' paper.
2-Matlab doesn't support Manhattan distance(I don't know why).

so

if I use 'sqeuclidean' default distance, the result will be close to Manhattan distance or I have to make my distance function(even I don't know how I can do it?).

link:https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmedoids.html

Thanks

Comment: Matlab calls Manhattan distance `cityblock` I think which is an option for `kmedoids`.

Comment: Thanks so much.  but I don't know why it's not a default distance instead of  'sqeuclidean'?